# Installing CLI for creating a plugin in Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

Where do you install the CLI on Cmd/Git or Node.js?
Is there an alternative way to installing CLI?

Answer (score 0):

You can install by writing that command "npm i -g smartface"

Answer (score 0):

Or you can download from Smartface.

https://www.smartface.io/products/cli/